# Add New Field to Form and Save it to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

First Problem:

I want to add new field with a button, so everytime the button is clicked it will create new field. I try using Jquery but I am new in this kind of programming language, can someone help me? Am I doing it right?

HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <?php
            $n = 0;
            $c = 0;
            echo "<Select>";
            do{
                if($c>10){$n="";}
                echo "<option>".$n.$c.":00</option>";
                echo "<option>".$n.$c.":30</option>";
                $c++;
            }while($c<24);
        ?>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<center><button id="addrow">Add Row</button></center>
```

Script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addrow").click(function(){
        consoloe.log("asdasda");
        $(tbody).append('<tr><td><?php
            $n = 0;
            $c = 0;
            echo "<Select>";
            do{
                if($c>10){$n="";}
                echo "<option>".$n.$c.":00</option>";
                echo "<option>".$n.$c.":30</option>";
                $c++;
            }while($c<24);
            ?></td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            </tr>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the error I get
[image]

[image]

This is The form look like [image]

Second Problem:

I think I need to give a name or ID for this field, because I need to save it to a database, can you give me some advice about POST method to insert multiple records with `mysqli`? How can I loop the insert statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One things about your code first: 1. You neeed to also close the "select" element before ""

My advice solution:
Use jQuery to add new field like so
`$("#addRow").click(function(){
$(tbody).append('<tr><td><select><option>Test1</option><option>Test2</option></select> </tr></td>);
});`

Then to loop through your form before you submit it you can use PHP. All the fields would be in the $_POST[] suberglobal so `foreach($_POST[] as $item){ //insert field in DB }`

You can also use AJAX to submit the form and iterate over it's fields in jQuery:

```
$.each("tbody tr td select", function(field){
   $.post("yourPHPfile.php", {name:field}, function(data){
  //on success handler
});
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: i try to close the tag with select, but i still got "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL", Maybe something wrong with my $(tbody)?

Comment: Btw you should not have new lines in the javascript append function, this results in an error by itself. Also why do any php code in the append function? PHP is only evaluated on the server side you can come up with some logic in JS to give appropriate attributes and names to your appended elements;

Comment: so the problem is with spacing and new lines. Okay you solved my first problem. With the second one, how i should name it ? or give i do so i can do loop insert in PHP. And how to remove row i have been add ?

Comment: Well what is your logic for those fields? You need to give each "select" a name attribute, so you can retrieve it in php by $_POST['name'] or just iterate over the whole $_POST array if you are sure it only contains your selects. In Javascript just include `<select name = "+$yourNameVariable+">` $yourNameVariable should be changed on each click of "AddRow" - you can just use an integer that you increment each time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by pure javascript , here is the example

```
   var yourHTML="<td><select>";
   yourHTML +="<option>--</option>";
   yourHTML +="<option>--</option>";
   yourHTML +="</select></td>";
   yourHTML +="<td><input type='text'></td>";

 function addRow(e){
            var tab=e;
            var rowCount=tab.rows.length;
            var row=tab.insertRow(rowCount);
            row.innerHTML=yourHTML;
            }
```

Now call addRow() on click of button

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addrow").click(function(){
         addRow(document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]);
       });
    });
```

LIVE http://jsfiddle.net/mailmerohit5/3outf4vm/

Comment: i need to put Select Type field with many option for Time and Input Type Text for Program's name

Comment: can you make the fiddle or demo? Sorry i really have a headache with this problem

Comment: thanks man. can you teach me how to remove the row that i have been add?

Comment: ofcourse mate , but i recommend you to edit the question to ask for that or move to a new question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90204/discussion-between-rohit-kumar-and-wingke).